# Why does typename std::iterator_traits<ForwardIt>::value_type work but not decltype(*ForwardIt())

Tags: c++, c++20

Why does this work ...

```
#include <iterator>

template<std::forward_iterator ForwardIt>
    requires std::integral<typename std::iterator_traits<ForwardIt>::value_type>
void radix_sort( ForwardIt begin, ForwardIt end )
{
    // ...
}

template
void radix_sort( int *, int * );
```

... but not this ...

```
#include <iterator>

template<std::forward_iterator ForwardIt>
    requires std::integral<decltype(*ForwardIt())>
void radix_sort( ForwardIt begin, ForwardIt end )
{
    // ...
}

template
void radix_sort( int *, int * );
```

ForwardIt has a default-constructor in my case (maybe std::forward_iterator<> does check this anyway).

I like the second solution because it looks more readable for me.

Comment: BTW: You can just use `std::iter_value_t` to get the value_type of an iterator.

Comment: Might be because `operator*` returns a `reference`, and not a `value_type`

Answer (score 0):

@StoryTeller was right. This code works:

```
#include <iterator>
#include <type_traits>

template<std::forward_iterator ForwardIt>
    requires std::is_integral_v<std::remove_cvref_t<decltype(*ForwardIt())>>
void radix_sort( ForwardIt begin, ForwardIt end )
{
    // ...
}


template
void radix_sort( int *, int * );
```

But then it becomes longer than ...

```
requires std::integral<std::iter_value_t<ForwardIt>>
```

... so the "proper" solution isn't preferrable over the above.

Comment: Even worse; the so-called short code might shoot you in the foot if used with an iterator type with no default ctor. The proper way is longer:`std::remove_cvref_t<decltype(*std::declval<ForwardIt>())>`.

Comment: I'll bet my right hand that no one uses iterators without default constructors.

Comment: I for 1 do. A default constructed iterator IMO can only mean general end - only iff possible to define a one-fits-all  end.